# Active Admin Search Status locale not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, activeadmin

[search status not translated (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMKRV.png)

English Locale (activeadmin.en.yml)

```
 en: 
   active_admin:
    search_status:
      headline: "Search status:"
```

Japanese Locale (activeadmin.ja.yml)

```
ja:
  active_admin:
    search_status:
      headline: "検索条件:"
```

I already have these translations in my yml files but I don't know why it won't work. I also found that ActiveAdmin uses this code `I18n.t("active_admin.search_status.headline")` I've already searched for issues in ActiveAdmin Github page and here on StackOverflow but I can't find any same issue I'm having right now.

Comment: Do other Japanese translations, that are not for active admin, work?

Comment: @MaksimKalmykov yes, other translation works, btw my activeadmin version is 1.0.0.pre4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code Activeadmin seems to have a bug.

The following line seems to be executed only once and does not change with the current locale

```
ActiveAdmin::SidebarSection.new I18n.t("active_admin.search_status.headline"), only: :index, if: -> { params[:q] || params[:scope] } do
```

Another line of code in activeadmin is like this and is working properly whenever the locale is changed

```
ActiveAdmin::SidebarSection.new :filters, only: :index, if: ->{ active_admin_config.filters.any? } do
```

So it seems that it would be better to pass a symbol instead.
Here is a patch(add this to an intializer) you can add to make it work:

```
module ActiveAdmin
  module Filters
    module ResourceExtension
      def search_status_section
        ActiveAdmin::SidebarSection.new :headline, only: :index, if: -> { params[:q] || params[:scope] } do
          active = ActiveAdmin::Filters::Active.new(resource_class, params)

          span do
            h4 I18n.t("active_admin.search_status.current_scope"), style: 'display: inline'
            b active.scope, style: "display: inline"

            div style: "margin-top: 10px" do
              h4 I18n.t("active_admin.search_status.current_filters"), style: 'margin-bottom: 10px'
              ul do
                if active.filters.blank?
                  li I18n.t("active_admin.search_status.no_current_filters")
                else
                  active.filters.each do |filter|
                    li do
                      span filter.body
                      b filter.value
                    end
                  end
                end
              end
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also, add a `headline` key on your locale file:

```
 sidebars:
   filters: "検索条件"
   search_status: "検索状態"
   headline: "TODO Search status:"
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, it seems to be a fault at my activeadmin version. I've followed your solution and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, your `yml` files should look like this:

activeadmin.en.yml:

```
en:
  active_admin:
    search_status:
      headline: "Search status:"
```

activeadmin.ja.yml:

```
ja:
  active_admin:
    search_status:
      headline: "検索条件:"
```

Comment: yes, it's like that, I just simplified the views since its understood that activeadmin.ja.yml must start with ja: and likewise to activeadmin.en.yml

Comment: Does `I18n.t("active_admin.search_status.headline")` work for `ja` locale in Rails console? Set `I18n.locale = "ja"` before.